# How can Usercontrol access the Webmethod using Jquery and Json

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, web-services

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //hide the branch
    var noteServiceUrl = "../../../AJAX/Common/BankingServiceAjax.svc/";
    var proxyNotes = new serviceProxy(noteServiceUrl);
    OnGetNotes();
    function OnGetNotes() {

        proxyNotes.invoke("SearchBranchesByBankID",
                            { "request":
                                    {
                                        "BankID": 1

                                    }
                            }, OnGetNotesComplete, OnError);

    }

    function OnGetNotesComplete(result) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        var notes = obj.Notes;
    }
```

I cannot access the BankingServiceAjax.svc by usercontrol, But if do this in page, I can access the Service. The URL is correct I think I lack only one attribute that might access the BankingService in my Usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

it is going to be done in an AJAX call similar to this

```
  $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: 'http://fastmotorcycleservice.cloudapp.net/FastMotorcycleListService.svc/list/Bruno',
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
```

Google is good too - [How To Consume svc Webservice using jQuery](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2011/11/17/how-to-consume-restful-services-using-jquery-and-or-javascript.aspx)